# Radical with pattern

Tags: calculus

Let $a =111 \ldots 1$, where the digit $1$ appears $2018$ consecutive times.

Let $b = 222 \ldots 2$, where the digit $2$ appears $1009$ consecutive times.

Without using a calculator, evaluate $\sqrt{a − b}$.

Comment: What have you tried.  As a suggestion:  start with smaller number.  $(11,2), (1111,22), \cdots$.  See if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: The number will be an increasing number of 3. For instance, 3 then 33, then 333, etc. What is the algebraic method to solve this problem is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a= \overbrace{11\ldots11}^{2018} = \dfrac{10^{2018}-1}{9}$

$b= \overbrace{22\ldots22}^{1009} = 2\cdot\dfrac{10^{1009}-1}{9}$

$\Rightarrow a-b = \dfrac{10^{2018}-1}{9}-2\cdot\dfrac{10^{1009}-1}{9} =  \dfrac{10^{2018}-2\cdot10^{1009}+1}{9} = \left(\dfrac{10^{1009}-1}{3} \right)^2$

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{a-b} = \dfrac{10^{1009}-1}{3} = \overbrace{33\ldots33}^{1009}$

Comment: how did you come up with ((10^2018)-1)/9

Comment: $9a = 99...99 = 10^{2018}-1$

Comment: why do you multiply b by 2?

Comment: because $b = 2\cdot 11\ldots 11$

Comment: oh ok. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
  a &= \frac{10^{2018}-1}{9} \\
  b &= \frac{2(10^{1009}-1)}{9} \\
  a-b &= \frac{10^{2018}-2\times10^{1009}+1}{9} \\
  &= \frac{(10^{1009}-1)^{2}}{9} \\
\end{align}

**Can you proceed?**

Comment: how did you solve for a?

Comment: @SamRalph A whole bunch of $9$'s divided by $9$ is the same number of $1$'s.

Comment: I understand. I am confused as to why b is multiplied by 2 (2nd line).

Comment: @SamRalph It's a whole bunch of $1$'s (using the same idea as the previous expression) multiplied by $2$ to give you a string of $2$'s. He's just writing down an expression for $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a=\sum_{i=0}^{2017}10^i $$
$$=\frac {10^{2018}-1}{10-1} $$
$$b=2\sum_{i=0}^{1008}10^i $$
$$=2\frac {10^{1009}-1}{10-1}$$

$$9 (a-b)=10^{2018}-2.10^{1009}+1$$
$$=(10^{1009}-1)^2$$

then

$$\sqrt {a-b}=\frac {10^{1009}-1}{3} $$

$=333...333.$ (1009  consecutive times).

Comment: why do you guys subtract 1?

Comment: about  which one you ask ?

Comment: the first step in the problem.

Comment: what formula are you using?

Comment: @SamRalph It is a geometric sum.

Comment: @SamRalph $ 1+a+a^2+a^3+...a^n=\frac {a^n-1}{a-1} $

Comment: oh ok.  This is very helpful. Could you also explain the step with 9(a-b)=10^2018-2.10, etc...

Comment: @SamRalph You replace $a$ by $10$. It is a well known formula.

Comment: also, why do you multiply b by 2?

Comment: @SamRalph $b=2+2×10+2×100+2×1000+... $$

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I am still not understanding why b is multiplied by 2. Wait, is it because you want to make b equal to a? I understand now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
N=\sum_{i=0}^{1008} 10^i =\underbrace{11\cdots 1}_{\text{1009 ones}} \\
M=10^{1009}+1 
\end{eqnarray*}
note that $M-2=9N$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
a=NM \\
b=2N
\end{eqnarray*}
So $a-b=9N^2$ and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{a-b} = 3N=\underbrace{\color{red}{33\cdots 3}}_{\text{1009 threes}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How did you come up with M?

Comment: $M$ is an obvious factor of $a$ ?